# Поиск уникального значения

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос, count

Суть запроса:Вывод Топ 3 месяца с указанием года по количеству уникальных клиентов за 2018-2019 год.

На текущем этапе я могу только подсчитать количество посещений по месяцам и годам.

То есть допустим клиент был 4 августа 2018 года и 2 ноября 2018 года. Для августа он уникальный, а для ноября уже нет. Вот я и не понимаю как мне сравнивать.

Сам запрос:

```
select top (3) year([Дата посещения]), MONTH([Дата посещения]), 
    count(year([Дата посещения])+'-'+ MONTH([Дата посещения]))
    from Посещения
    group by year([Дата посещения]), MONTH([Дата посещения])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю - под уникальными понимаются клиенты, которые впервые обратились в 2018-2019 годах? Т.е. Вам нужно посчитать 3 месяца, в которых приток новых клиентов был наибольшим за эти 2 года?

Answer (score 3):

Вот один из вариантов решения:

```
;WITH [CTE]
AS
(
    SELECT [Id клиента]
          ,MIN([Дата посещения]) AS [Дата посещения]
      FROM [Посещения]
     GROUP BY [Id клиента]
)
SELECT TOP(3)
       YEAR([Дата посещения]) AS [Год посещения]
      ,MONTH([Дата посещения]) AS [Месяц посещения]
      ,COUNT([Id клиента]) AS [Кол-во уникальных клиентов]
  FROM [CTE]
 WHERE [Дата посещения] BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '2018-01-01', 126) AND CONVERT(date, '2019-12-31', 126)
 GROUP BY YEAR([Дата посещения]), MONTH([Дата посещения])
 ORDER BY COUNT([Id клиента]) DESC
```

Тут мы сначала находим дату первого посещения для каждого клиента, а потом уже группируем по датам и вычисляем количество. При этом если клиент первый раз приходил в 2017 году, он не будет учтён в этой выборке. Если же нужно, чтобы клиент приходивший в 2017 и 2018 годах учитывался как уникальный для 2018 года, нужно перенести условие WHERE из внешнего запроса внуть обобщённого табличного выражения (Common Table Expression).

P.S. Скорее всего это не самое оптимальное решение с точки зрения производительности. Если запрос должен будет выполняться часто, то стоит подумать как его можно улучшить.

Answer (score 0):

Если в целом описание @Oksi из первого комментария к вопросу корректное, с чем я вроде согласен, то получается вам надо взять все первые визиты клиентов за эти годы и отбросить оставшиеся, а затем посчитать их по месяцам.

```
WITH first AS (
    SELECT client_id
         , year(vdate) as y
         , month(vdate) as m
         , row_number() over (partition by client_id order by vdate)  as rn
    FROM visits
    WHERE year(vdate) IN (2018, 2019) 
)
SELECT top 3 y, m, count(client_id) as cc
FROM first as f
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY y, m
ORDER BY cc desc
```

так что ли?

*зы: код примерный*

Comment: если надо взять реально новых клиентов, которые впервые появились в 18-19 года и раньше не бывали, то условие на годы надо во внешний запрос переместить.